# How to check in jQuery if a Bootstrap tab isn't clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have tabs in Bootstrap:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li>tab1</li>
  <li>tab2</li>
  <li>tab3</li>
  <li>tab4</li>
  <li>tab5</li>
</ul>

<p id="message"></p>
```

How can I make it so that when no tab is clicked a message 'Please select a tab' is shown?

I have made a `<p id="message"></p>` underneath the tabs, I just need to insert the message when no tab is clicked and remove the message when a tab is clicked but I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: What is `<li ...>`? Post normal HTML.

Comment: At least one tab will be active in the beginning right? how can you say there won't be any `tab` active?

Comment: Because no tabs have "active"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Bootstrap tabs you also need content containers. In this case I would put message div into `tab-content` div:

```
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
    <p id="message">Please select some tab</p>
</div>
```

... and make it hide in case anything is selected with simple CSS rule:

```
.tab-pane.active ~ #message {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
.tab-pane.active ~ #message {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">Home</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages</div>
  <p id="message">Please select some tab</p>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/1VaF3NoTRK4X2pnd651G?p=info

Answer (score 1):

The solution @dfsq has posted is more elegant as compared to what follows. However, if your situation doesn't allow you to change your HTML markup, here is another way to do it.

```
var selectedTab = $('.nav-tabs li.active');

if(selectedTab.length === 0){
    $('#message').html('Please select tab');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap has 'shown.bs.tab' event to capture if the tab is clicked. you can make use of it as shown below.

```
$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
   console.log(e.target) // activated tab
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In `BootStrap` when a tab is clicked the the corresponding `li` element gets an `active` class, while the other `li` tags don't have this class until clicked.

You can use the following code to check if any tab is clicked:

```
$(function(){
    CheckTabClick()
})

$(".nav-tabs li").click(function(){
    CheckTabClick()
})

function CheckTabClick(){
  var tab_clicked = $(".nav-tabs li.active")

  if (tab_clicked.length == 0){
      $("#message").show();
  }
    else{
     $("#message").hide();
    }
}
```